# Should there be at least one assert in a unit test? If so, why?

Tags: unit-testing, googletest

If we take for example gtest, we have the option to use asserts like ASSERT_NE or checks like EXPECT_NE. One of my colleagues pointed out that I should have at least one assert in my test preferably the condition which checks the main objective.
So, far I was used to using ASSERTs in places where the continuation of test is useless, and EXPECTs in places where the test could continue.
What is the correct way of using ASSERTs and EXPECTs?

Comment: Sounds like you have it right - a test should have at least one `EXPECT`, but it only needs `ASSERT` if there's something that would obstruct the test itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between `EXPECT_*` and `ASSERT_*` macros is that assertions stop the test immediately if it failed, while expectations allow it to continue.

Here's what GoogleTest Primer says about it:

> Usually `EXPECT_*` are preferred, as they allow more than one failures to be reported in a test. However, you should use `ASSERT_*` if it doesn't make sense to continue when the assertion in question fails.

So, to illustrate it:

```cpp
TEST_F(myTest, test1)
{
    uut.doSomething();
    ASSERT_EQ(uut.field1, expectedvalue1);
    ASSERT_EQ(uut.field2, expectedvalue2);
}
```

If `field1` doesn't match assertion, test fails and you have no idea if `field2` is correct or not. This makes debugging much more difficult.

Choice between these options is mostly **matter of agreement** in your team, but I'd stick to GTest proposition of using `EXPECT_*` as the backbone of all checks and `ASSERT_*` only if you test something crucial to continue, without which further part of test doesn't make any sense (for example, if your unit under test was not created correctly).